# How do I render different components on a page according to some action defined inside those said components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

If I have the following App component:

```
function App() {
  if(test)
    return <Component1 />;
  else
    return <Component2 />;
}
```

But the value of `test` (true/false) is dependent on a button inside the two respective components. Clicking the button should flip the value of `test` (i.e. set to `true` if `false` and vice versa). How would I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `test` on App level and pass down a callback

```
function App() {
  let [test, setTest] = useState(false)
  if(test)
    return <Component1 setTest={setTest}/>;
  else
    return <Component2 setTest={setTest}/>;
}
```

*inside* the component you can implement the flipping logic like

```
props.setTest(ps=>!ps);
```

Comment: Would `return <button onClick={setTest((ps) => !ps)}>Click</button>` work inside my Component1?

Comment: @UvaisHassan yes - try; you may need to use `props.setTest..`

Comment: It didn't work for some reason but I think I got the concept. I'll try and find a workaround. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent component should should have a state and provide child components with a proper way to change that state. Similar implementation as [@gmoniava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165884/4986875) provided but without hooks may look like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      test: false
    }
  }

  changeState() {
    this.setState({ test: !this.state.test });
  }

  render() {
    const { test } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {test && <Component1 onChangeState={this.changeState} />}
        {!test && <Component2 onChangeState={this.changeState} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`App` component contains state with `test` property in it. Also it has `changeState` function which toggle `test` in state.

`changeState` function is passed to child components as props. Child component calls that function inside which triggers parent function and state is changed:

```
function Component1(props) {
  return (<button onClick={props.onChangeState}>Component 1</button>);
}
```

Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcbanr0k/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  const example = () => {
    setTest(!test);
  };

  if (!test) {
    return <Component1 example={example} />;
  } else {
    return <Component2 example={example} />;
  }
}
```

and inside `Component1` (and `Component2`):

```
function Component1(props) {
  return <button onClick={() => props.example()}>Click</button>;
}
```

Passing `setTest` directly as prop didn't work.